# Why is my button breaking when the text is too long

Tags: html, css

I have a css button and I need its width to be 250px, the problem is that when the text in the button is too big the button seems to break in half instead of wrapping.

I have `white-space: normal` applied to the button but the break is still happening.

```css
.button {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px white;
  white-space: normal;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
.container {
  max-width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a class="button">my button whose text is longer than 250px</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes on top of using `white-space: normal;` ups will also need the element to be `display: inline-block;`

```css
.button {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px white;
  white-space: normal;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
.container {
  max-width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a class="button">my button whose text is longer than 250px</a>
</div>
```